# ListView onItemClick and DelayedConfirmationView onTimerSelected triggered with same click

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, wear-os

I did a SO search but didn't really know what to look for. So sorry if this is a dumb question.  I'm new to android programming and I'm trying to make a wearable app with a listview.  When the user clicks an item, it should show a delayed confirmation view that allows the user to cancel the selection. I have an activity with two views, a ListView and a DelayedConfirmationView.

When a list item is clicked, the timer is started and delayedConfirmationView is shown.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    mSelectedPosition = position;
    setListViewVisible(false);

    // Two seconds to cancel the action
    mDelayedView.setTotalTimeMs(2000);
    // Start the timer
    mDelayedView.start();
}
```

I switch between the two views like this:

```
private void setListViewVisible(boolean listViewVisible) {
    if(listViewVisible){
        mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mDelayedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{

        mListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mDelayedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

If the cancel button is pressed, I switch back to the listview so the user can revise their selection:

```
@Override
public void onTimerSelected(View view) {
    // cancel selected, so go back to listview
    setListViewVisible(true);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I hit the cancel button, it also triggers the onItemClickListener for the listview, so it instantly transfers back to the delayed confirmation view.

I feel like the answer should be simple, but it's strange to me that the same click triggers both onTimerSelected and onItemClick.

Edit:
I tried adding a delay before switching the views to see if the view transition was too fast and picking up the button press.

Here are the logs BEFORE the delay was added:

> D/AddClimbActivity: onCreate()
>   D/AddClimbActivity: setListViewVisible(true)
>   D/AddClimbActivity: onItemClick
>   D/AddClimbActivity: setListViewVisible(false)
>   D/AddClimbActivity: onTimerSelected <-- PRESSING THE CANCEL BUTTON
>   D/AddClimbActivity: setListViewVisible(true)
>   D/AddClimbActivity: onItemClick    <-- UNEXPECTED BEHAVIOR
>   D/AddClimbActivity: setListViewVisible(false)
>   D/AddClimbActivity: onTimerFinished

New onTimerSelected:

```
    @Override
public void onTimerSelected(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onTimerSelected");
    // cancel selected, so go back to listview
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            setListViewVisible(true);
        }
    }, 50);
    Log.d(TAG, "onTimerSelected exit");
}
```

And the new log:

> D/AddClimbActivity: onCreate()
>   D/AddClimbActivity: setListViewVisible(true)
>   D/AddClimbActivity: onItemClick
>   D/AddClimbActivity: setListViewVisible(false)
>   D/AddClimbActivity: onTimerSelected
>   D/AddClimbActivity: onTimerSelected exit
>   D/AddClimbActivity: setListViewVisible(true)
>   D/AddClimbActivity: onTimerFinished  <-- UNEXPECTED BEHAVIOR

So by adding the delay I get some unintended behavior where both the onTimerSelected and onTimerFinshed callbacks are called.

Comment: instead of using onItemClickListener , perform click events inside your adapters if you have more than one views to click in your element of listview

Comment: @vikramthakur Not sure what you mean.  I only have one view in each element of my listview, I use simple_list_item_1 with a single textview.

Comment: could you please check will `onItemClick` be called is you comment `setListViewVisible(true);` in `onTimerSelected` callback? Thank you.

Comment: where is your cancel button ?

Try 1 thing , in your cancel button click event , toggle visibility of the listview after a delay , just to check whether is listview item being clicked with the cancel

Comment: I tried adding a delay, but it didn't fix the problem.  It did stop onItemClick from being called, but now both onTimerSelected and onTimerFinished both get called.  See edit in post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to add two things to get this to work.  I had to delay the view switch (see the edit in my post) as well as setting the delayed confirmation view listener to null so onTimerFinished didn't get called.  It seems strange that android wouldn't cancel the timer when it's selected by default, but maybe there's a use case for having the user press the button without the timer being stopped?

Anyways, here's what my code ended up being:

```
@Override
public void onTimerSelected(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onTimerSelected");

    mDelayedView.setPressed(true);

    // Prevent onTimerFinished from being heard.
    mDelayedView.setListener(null);

    // cancel selected, so go back to listview
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            setListViewVisible(true);
        }
    }, 50);
}
```